# SQL Linked Server Named pipes provider - error 5

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have SQL server 2012 installed on a machine. I connected it successfully using Linked Server from the another machine. however when i tried to connected the same machine from another labtop  which is on the same network i got the following error: please note that i have checked i can assess the sql server from SQL Server Management studio but it does not connected if i try to do it using linked server. I have checked tcp, named pipes are enable. Any suggestion

**Error**:

```
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MAL_SQL" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MAL_SQL" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

Comment: did You enabled `Named Pipes Provider` in SQL Configuration Manager

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly disable Names Pipes (which I doubt you need, because this is 1990's technology that was predominantly used in IBM Token Ring networks). If you keep it enabled, just make sure that TCP/IP comes first in the order of client protocols (in the SQL Server Client Configuration Manager).
The fact that the client is even trying to use Named Pipes indicates that it could not reach your server via TCP/IP. Management Studio connects with the Native Client and not OLEDB.

Did you do what the error message says - check if your instance name is correct? You must have specified your linked server connection incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem and I got it solved by doing these steps:

1) Go to Network Connections

2) Click on Alt key and select Advanced and then Advanced Settings

3) On Adapters and Bindings tab and in the Connections section, make Ethernet the first connection

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to do two things:

1. Make sure the SQL Server Browser Service was running on the target SQL Server
2. Allow TCP Port 1433 in the Firewall on the target SQL Server.